On Windows desktop app isConnected method doesn't return boolean value in flutter
await ConnectivityWrapper.instance.isConnected returns List instead of a boolean value on Windows Desktop app

Given how isConnected is declared it seems very unlikely that it can even return anything but a boolean. Can you edit your question to show a minimal-but-complete/standalone repro that we can copy/paste to run?
